# Can Facebook app developers see how many/which user-to-user messages from their apps are being reported as spam?

Tags: facebook, message, send, spam

The send dialog ( http://www.facebook.com/dialog/send?app_id=123050457758183&name=People%20Argue%20Just%20to%20Win&link=http://www.nytimes.com/2011/06/15/arts/people-argue-just-to-win-scholars-assert.html&redirect_uri=http://www.example.com/response) shows the originating app at the bottom of the message - in this case Cool Social App.

Is there a way for the maker of the originating app to track how many and/or which messages are being reported as spam?

I don't see information on this stuff in Insights.

Many thanks,

Nick

Answer (score 2):

You can see this information through App Insights, under the News Feed > Spam tab. Replace APPID with your own Apps ID in this URL:

`https://developers.facebook.com/apps/APPID/insights?sk=as_APPID`

Comment: Thanks Matthew.  But my app doesn't post to the News Feed - it lets users send each other messages via the Send Dialog.  I can't find Facebook message-specific Spam reporting.  Do you (or others) know if it exists?

Comment: That does not exist in the Insights tool unfortunately.